# How to get file path of product page?

Tags: magento-1.7

can you please help me that how can i get file path from magento web app product page.
I want to customize the product page. I couldn't find a way to customize my product page template. so any body can please tell me that how can i do this and solve my problem.  i am working on magento version 9.x.

Answer (score 3):

you can enable template hints to see from which file the content is coming.

```
Steps to get Template Path Hints:

1) Login to Magento Admin panel
2) Go to System->Configuration.
3) The Template Path and Block name will only appear for current website. So change the Current Configuration Scope to ‘Main Website’.
4) Go to the Advanced section and click on Developers.
5) Expand the Debug tab.
5) Set the Template Path Hints to 'Yes'.
6) Click on 'Save Configuration' button.
7) Open Magento user panel and see the template path hints. It shows each file where the page element is located in.
```

for more information go to http://insync.co.in/how-to-enable-template-path-and-block-name-hints-in-magento-commerce/

Answer (score 1):

Please enable the Template Path Hints. and refresh the product page and open your file which you want to edit/change..